# JQuery how to remove "id" from a part of html content

Tags: jquery, html, selector

I want to do something like this:

```
var html = $("#media").html();
$("#multimedia-content").append(html);
$("#multimedia-content").filter("*").removeAttr("id");
```

The 3th line fails, I want to remove all id's from this part of html but I don't know how to do the selection.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not either call the `removeAttr` on the first line, or use `$('#multimedia-content *').removeAttr('id');` Also, if this is jQuery >=1.6, look in to using [`.rempveProp`](http://api.jquery.com/removeProp/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Personally, i would try this:

```
$('#media')                         // grab the media content
  .clone()                          // make a duplicate of it
  //.find('*')                        // find all elements within the clone
    .removeAttr('id')               // remove their ID attributes
  //.end()                            // end the .find()
  .appendTo('#multimedia-content'); // now add it to the media container
```

*If you'd like #media to lose its ID as well, remove the `.find()` and `.end()` lines, otherwise un-comment them.*

Comment: Your example leaves duplicate id's!  Specifically ***"media"***.

Comment: @Brock: Indeed, media's ID isn't changed, but OP wasn't looking to change it. Bad behavior, yes, Simple fix, also a yes (remove the `.find()` and `.end()` calls and all is better.)

Comment: Huh?  I see no evidence that OP wasn't looking to avoid **duplicate** ID's.  That's probably why he did that `.removeAttr("id");` in the first place. But, add the `.find()`-and-`.end()` fix to your answer and pick up another vote.

Answer (score 3):

You should do:

```
$("#multimedia-content *").removeAttr("id");
```

This will remove all the ids of the elements inside `#multimedia-content`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("*[id], #multimedia-content").removeAttr("id");
```

This way it only removes the id attribute from elements that contain the id attribute.

Answer (score 0):

To remove any `id` attributes from any child elements of `#multimedia-content`:

```
$("#multimedia-content").find().each(function() {
    $(this).removeAttr("id");
});
```