# Removing IDs from HTML elements before saving them to database

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a application which can save user-created HTML templates. Here, the user will have some HTML components at his disposal and would be able to create static HTML pages using those components.

I am auto saving the content of the page using a javascript function.

```
     function saveContent(){    
        //var getContent=$('#mainWrap').children().removeAttr('id');
        var $getContent=$('#mainWrap');
        var $finalContent=$getContent.children().removeAttr('id');
        var auto="auto";
        var pageId = <?php echo $pageId;?>; 
        var webId  = <?php echo $webId;?>;
        var userId = <?php echo $userId;?>;
        $.ajax({
            url:"auto_save.php",
            type:"POST",
            dataType:"text",
            data:"txtComp="+$('#mainWrap').html()+"&auto="+auto+"&pageId="+pageId+"&webId="+webId+"&userId="+userId
        }); 
    }   

    var interval = 1000 * 60 * 0.30; // where X is your every X minutes
    setInterval(saveContent,interval);
```

**Issue:** I want to to remove the IDs from the HTML components that the user saves, because the IDs are auto generated and not needed when the user **publishes the template** (on his domain after creation). I have a main wrapper that wraps the entire page called `id=mainWrap`. If I try to remove the IDs like this  `$('#mainWrap').children().removeAttr('id');` they are also removed from the current context of the DOM, i.e they are removed from the page where the user is editing his template.

**Question:** How can I remove the IDs from the HTML elements without affecting the current context of the `mainWrap` object?

I tried assigning it to another object like this

```
    var $getContent=$('#mainWrap');
    var $finalContent=$getContent.children().removeAttr('id');
```

but still it failed.

Any comments or corrections on whether this is possible? Or am I going about this the wrong way?

**Update** : The issue is solved to some extent.
 Next I want to add the id's back when the user comes back to the edit page.
 I get the above saved content using this code

```
    <?php
    $sqlEdit = "select revisionContent from tbl_revision where revisionId='".$_SESSION['contentId']."'"; //The query to get the record
    $rsEdit = $dbObj->tep_db_query($sqlEdit);//The database object to execute the query   
    $resEdit = $dbObj->getRecord($rsEdit);                                                                                       
    $IdLessContent = $resEdit['revisionContent'];//Variable with the record

     ?>
```

Now,I want to use this PHP variable in javascript,so I did this.

```
  <script language="javascript">
    var getSavedContent = '<?php echo json_encode($IdLessContent); ?>';
    var trimmedCont=($.trim(getSavedContent).slice(1));
    //console.log(trimmedCont);
    var lengthCont= trimmedCont.length;
    var trimmedCont=$.trim(trimmedCont.slice(0,lengthCont-1));
    var pageContent=$('<div class="addId">').append(trimmedCont);  //Here I tried creating a div dynamically and appending the content to the div.But now I am not able to manipulate or work on this dyamic div and get NULL when I alert saying $('.addId').html();
    $('.addId').children().attr('id', 'test');               //I tried doing this but does not work
```

This is not working.Can you throw some light on it

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6619452/jquery-how-to-remove-id-from-a-part-of-html-content ?

Comment: @Jules Thank you.I will give it a try and check if it works in my scenario.Wonder why I didn't I find it ! :P

Comment: You should be doing this on the server side instead.

Comment: @Jack Can you elaborate a bit?Didn't get your point.Thanks

Comment: @Jules When I say `.clone().appendTo($('#someId'))` Do I need to create a div with `id="someId"` ?I want it to be done dynamically ,i tried something like this `$('<div class="addId">').append(getSavedContent).html())`,but I don't get the children when I do `.children` on the `div` with class addId

Comment: Let me put it differently, what would stop someone from submitting a bogus HTML value to your script which is then used blindly?

Comment: @user2000339 Jack is right that you risk that someone manages to bypass your filter if you just do it clientside, but you find a working way to do it in my answer below.

Comment: @Jack ok..you mean I should do it server side say using PHP.But wouldn't it be a load on the browser in case I have many components?Can I tackle the security vulnerabilities By any means this way??Any example how it can become i

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just cycle through the elements in your `#mainWrap` and remove the `id` like:

```
var getContent = $('#mainWrap');
var finalContent = getContent.parent().clone().find('*').removeAttr('id');
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/7m8g4/6/

Security wise you should realize this is a client-side script that is removing the `id` attributes from the html. There are ways though to manipulate the JavaScript or to bypass it by (for instance) calling the URL in your Ajax request directly with false data.

So you should never rely on your JavaScript only. Make sure your code will not cause problems if for any reason the JavaScript doesn't act as expected. You can do this for instance by searching for `id` attributes (use a [regex](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)) and generate an error message in case there are still some `id` attributes found. Another way would be to remove them server-side (in PHP) as well if any are found. To achieve this you could do a regex search and replace the matches with empty strings or by making use of substrings. Up to you!

Hope it all makes sense!

**EDIT**

If you want to add new `id` attributes back later on you can do something like:

```
var newContent = $(finalContent).first().wrap('<div class="addId" />');
newContent = $(newContent).parent().find('*').each(function(index, value) {
   $(this).attr('id', index);
});
```

See that in work [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7m8g4/7/).

Comment: @Jack ok you mean I should handle it using say PHP on server side!but Won't it add load on the site when there are number of components?Is there any way to handle security vulnerabilities!!Also how can it be handled using PHP?

Comment: @user2000339 Of course it will add load on the website, but this should be neglectable in your case. Did you try the script I gave you? Did it help? I will add some security tips to my answer.

Comment: @Jack The reason I was doing it at client side is bcoz,when the user comes and tries to reedit his page,he should again have the id's in place to edit the components.As,I had to attach them back(I am saving the content to database),I wanted it to happen fast as there would be **images + content** in future on the pages.Currently I am sending an ajax request to autosave the stuff.Not sure if it can done by any other means

Comment: Can I use REST api to perform the same auto save operation?I am new to it and not sure if it fits the scenario I am in?

Comment: Its working independently as on fiddle but when I add it to my code,it alerts blank box!! :P Not getting why?

Comment: @coderunner Your Ajax request is fine for this usage. We are just saying that you should not **only** rely on JavaScript to filter out the `id` attributes. Make sure you have a backup plan and your entire system doesn't crash in case there is some unexpected content reaching your `auto_save.php` page (such as `id` attributes).
If it alerts a blank box in your code you did something wrong. The code is fine. Maybe you should adapt the `#mainWrap` identifier to whatever you need in your code. (We have no insight on your HTML structure)

Comment: Yes I got the mistake,in my case the parent attribute in the code was the culprit as my `mainWrap` did not have a parent.It worked and I have accepted the answer.Couldn't UPVOTE due to reputation limits! :P Now,I also want to re-edit the content so I will need the id's back when the user comes and tries to update his page.I am not able to attach the id's back to components.I just want add attribute using `attr('name','value')`.The id's would be generated dynamically.Please check my UPDATED quesstion! Thank you for the help

Comment: @coderunner I have updated my answer to show you an example on how to add the `id` attributes back.